# WPF label text Fragmented

Tags: wpf, devexpress, text-rendering, devexpress-wpf

I am currently developing an WPF app with DevExpress tools and encountered a very strange display bug of a label, displayed a fragmented Text:

[image: WPF label Fragmented]

As you can clearly see, all other labels are not effected but only this particular one. If zoomed in you can see that the label is rendered with artifacts:

[image]

This even continues to happen if i increase the font size to "25":
[image]

The label itself is nothing else then this:

```
<Label DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       Content="{lex:Loc View.Application.Realm.CreateNew}" />
```

Apart from DevExpress there are no global Styles or settings done to rendering.

Comment: What is that content object?  Are you sure it's not an image file? If not did you try changing font to something else?  Or maybe take a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2009/10/21/new-wpf-features-textformattingmode-for-clear-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your label doesn't have any rendering issue, another control with white text is positioning itself over your label, check your XAML to see what could be that other control.